# Jenkins Failed to install nodejs plugin

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using JENKINS 1.574V, trying to install nodejs plugin V1.2.6 from manage plugins->available tab.
Its throwing below error - 
java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to install nodejs plugin

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to initialize

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/tasks/SimpleBuildWrapper
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

Please help me how to solve this issue, its blocking me

Answer (score 0):

Do update your Jenkins to the latest version available and then try! This link may help you! https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/06/upgrade-jenkins-and-plugins/